# Way to automatically click button on page with unique tag & class name via Javascript

Tags: javascript, tags, autofill, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to automatically click a button on a webpage that has a specific tag and class. I am using Tampermonkey (Javascript userscripts) to achieve this. Here is an image of the CSS/HTML elements that I need to interact with:

[image]

The element and button that I want to interact with is highlighted in the image above and contains the following HTML:

```
<li data-v-29761082 class="list-item">
```

I've been using the following in an attempt to click the button in the console, but to no avail:

```
document.querySelector('li data-v-29761082.list-item')[0].click();
```

The "data-v-29761082" section is throwing me off, and I don't know how to incorporate these characters into the query selector. I tried to treat the entire name as a single tag, but that hasn't worked. I am simply trying to click the button that is highlighted in the screenshot, but I am still searching for a solution.

Realistically, I will likely need to use waitForkeyElements to get the code to work automatically on the page from Tampermonkey, but right now I am simply looking for a way to click the highlighted button above using specific tag and class information. If there is another way to solve the problem (maybe different elements, etc) that would also suffice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will you try it? document.querySelector('li[data-v-29761082].list-item').click();

Comment: Worked in the console! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This is how you querySelect `li.list-item[data-v-29761082]`

`.click()` is jquery. so either you have do do this with jquery:

```
$(document.querySelector("li.list-item[data-v-29761082]")).trigger('click');
```

or even

```
$("li.list-item[data-v-29761082]").trigger('click')
```

or this with plain js:

```
var item = document.querySelector("li.list-item[data-v-29761082]");

if (item) {
    item.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
}
```